# Difference between Keras model.fit using only batch_size and using only steps_per_epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, training-data

When I run `model.fit` using both `batch_size` and `steps_per_epoch` parameters I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: If steps_per_epoch is set, the `batch_size` must be None.
```

So, from this error and from the following piece of documentation [from keras Model(functional API)](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit)

> **batch_size:** Integer or None. Number of samples per gradient update. If
> unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.

> **steps_per_epoch:** Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples)
> before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When training
> with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.

I understand that both parameters are somehow equivalent. But, on my laptop, (with a GeForce 940M graphics card with 2GB of VRAM and training the cifar10 dataset) when I run `model.fit` with epochs parameter set to 256 the script runs fine and the feedback gave from keras is like this:

```
4608/50000 [=>............................] - ETA: 1:59 - loss: 0.8167 - acc: 0.7398
```

updating the first number always adding 256 units. However, when passing `steps_per_epoch` as the `number_train//batch_size` I run out of memory and cannot run my script unless I pass `batch_size` as 1.

So, how `model.fit` work with those parameters? What is the difference when I use just one of those instead of the other one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good question. What I observe from the source code ([[1]](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1025) and [[2]](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L146)) is that:

- When you set `batch_size`, the training data is sliced into batches of this size (see [L184](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L184)).
- When you set `steps_per_epoch`, if the training inputs are not framework-native tensors (this is the most common case), the *whole* training set is being fed into the network in a single batch (see [L152](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_arrays.py#L152)), and that's why you get the memory error.

Therefore, based on the implementation, I would advise to use the argument `steps_per_epoch` only when feeding through framework-native tensors (i.e. TensorFlow tensors with the first dimension being the batch size), and that is indeed a requirement. In order to do this, the arguments `x` and `y` from `model.fit` need to be set to `None`.

Comment: So, when I pass the data to the model through a generator and use the fit_generator function I just have the steps_per_epoch option because "keras" get to know the batch_size on the fly when the generator yields one element, am I right?

Comment: total_no_img = 50000 /n
batch_size = 10 /n
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = total_no_img / batch_size /n
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 50000 / 10 /n
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 5000 /n
/n
Still too much to fit in ram? /n
Here i'm only reading 50000 records from file..I have 333000 image dataset