# Combining Keras model.fit's `steps_per_epoch` with TensorFlow's Dataset API's `batch()`

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm looking at the performance and GPU usage during training of a CNN model with Keras+TensorFlow. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282989/difference-between-keras-model-fit-using-only-batch-size-and-using-only-steps-pe), I'm having a hard time to understand the combined use of Keras `model.fit`'s `steps_per_epoch` and TensorFlow's Dataset API's `.batch()`: I set a certain batch size on the input pipeline `dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)` and later I use

```py
fit = model.fit(dataset, epochs=num_epochs, steps_per_epoch=training_set_size//batch_size)
```

but I see that one can actually set any number of steps per epoch, even more than `training_set_size//batch_size`. From the documentation I understand that on Keras an epoch is not necessarily a pass over the entire training set as usually, but anyway I'm a bit confused and now I'm not entirely sure if I'm using it right.

Is `dataset.batch(batch_size)` + `steps_per_epoch=training_set_size//batch_size` defining a minibatch SGD that runs over the entire training set by minibatches of `batch_size` samples? Are epochs larger than  one pass over the training set if `steps_per_epoch` is set to more than `training_set_size//batch_size`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`steps_per_epoch` is the number of batches of your set batch size is ran through the network in one epoch.

You have set your `steps_per_epoch` to be `training_set_size//batch_size` for a good reason. This ensures all data are trained upon in one epoch, providing the number divides exactly (if not it rounds by the // operator).

That is to say if you had a batch size of 10 and a training set size of 30, then `steps_per_epoch = 3` ensures all data are used.

And to quote your question:

> "Are epochs larger than one pass over the training set if steps_per_epoch is set to more than training_set_size//batch_size?"

Yes. Some data will be passed through again in the same epoch.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I see now that my script really does what I want it to do.

Comment: How I wish I could find your answer earlier!